# How to Get Field Name With Query in Zend Framework

Tags: database, zend-framework

How to Get Field Name With Query in Zend Framework
Test "Select * From Test1,Test2"
how to get all field name in this query 
Zend Frame work cam do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but I believe the query is returned as an associative array (where the column name is the key), and so you can loop through the first record and pick up the column names, e.g.

```
$sql = 'Select * From Test1,Test2';

$result = $db->fetchAll($sql, 2);

foreach ($result[0] as $key => $value) {
 echo $key;
 ...
}
```

Comment: but not smart $result[0] will have lest 1 data in row
if don't have ,it wiill error :<

Comment: i will insert and delete for this ?

Comment: It'd be expensive and inefficient to create a dummy row for this purpose (3 queries), so you probably want to test the number of rows returned, and if it's zero, use one of the meta techniques Till describes.  Or better still, don't use 'select *' as it's not best practice; find out only the field names in advance (e.g. using Till's technique) and then use that to build your data queries.

Comment: But Zend dont't have fetch_field function same codeigniter better :<

Answer (score 1):

You could also issue `$db->describeTable('Test1')`, etc. before or after the query which would provide you with all the meta information you need. This query is pretty expensive though, so make sure to cache the response.

Also, if you're using a model which extends `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`, then you should have all this information already. In this case, all you need to do is access the protected property `$_metadata`.

HTH